# TintColor does not apply to my Complication when using rendering Mode "Template" (CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularClosedGaugeImage)

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I am currently trying to implement a
**CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularClosedGaugeImage**
but for some reason my icon keeps getting tinted blue.

When I change the tintColor of the WatchFace everything seems to be tinted the right way. But when I disable tinting on the WatchFace my Image will be colored blue for some reason.

I enabled the rendering Mode: **alwaystemplate** inside the asset catalog because my image is just black in the original version and I tint it in other parts of my app.

```
let gaugeProvider = CLKSimpleGaugeProvider(style: .fill, gaugeColor: color, fillFraction: progress)
let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularClosedGaugeImage(gaugeProvider: gaugeProvider, imageProvider: CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image))
```

I tried to apply a tintColor on the template and I also tried to apply a tintColor direclty to the image before passing it to the ImageProvider. Both Ideas doesnt result in the expected output.

```
let gaugeProvider = CLKSimpleGaugeProvider(style: .fill, gaugeColor: color, fillFraction: progress)
let imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image)
let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularClosedGaugeImage(gaugeProvider: gaugeProvider, imageProvider: imageProvider)
template.tintColor = .white // this has no effect
```

How can I set a default tint color when using **alwaysTemplate** as the rendering mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a Solution by myself.
I am now tinting the Image white and also rerendering it as a originalImage.

```
let imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image.withTintColor(.white, renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate).withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))
```

Comment: I'd be curious to understand why this works. Thanks for sharing this solution!